# Why can't I select multiple columns from a table?

Tags: python, sqlite

Not really sure what's going on.  DB code that was working just fine now does not.

```
def get_all_nodes(self) -> tuple:
    cursor = self.conn.cursor()
    query = 'SELECT node_id, guid FROM nodes'
    result = cursor.execute(query).fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    return result
```

This only returns the first column, rather than both.

The original code was:

```
def get_all_nodes(self) -> tuple:
    cursor = self.conn.cursor()
    query = 'SELECT * FROM nodes'
    result = cursor.execute(query).fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    return result
```

Once again, this only returns a single column.

If I run `SELECT * FROM nodes` using PyCharm's database console tool, against the same DB file, I get all columns and rows.

What can cause `SELECT * FROM` to only return the first column?  In this case, the database in question is just fine.  I can open, browse and edit this table using PyCharm's DB tool.  Not sure why `*` would only return the first column.

**EDIT:**

```
    result = db.get_all_nodes()
    for row in result:
        print(row)
```

This will print as many rows as there are in the db, except only a single column's data is printed  This happens whether I use `*` or a comma-separated list of all the columns in the query statement.

As I said, running exactly the same SQL using the PyCharm DB tool produces the expected result.

**EDIT 2:**

I just noticed the vote to close because it is not reproducible.  You are kidding me, right?  Of course it isn't easily reproducible.  I've been looking at this code for a couple of hours.  As far as I can tell, there's nothing whatsoever wrong with it.  That's why I posted for help.  Maybe there's a SQLite quirk or something of that kind that might cause such behavior.  This, I think, is the kind of thing that you won't know about unless you've seen it.  I am hoping someone has.

And, yes, should that be the case, the answer would be very helpful to others who might run into something like this in the future.

**EDIT 3: Discovered how this is happening**

In a comment, Dan Getz mentioned row factories.  I am not using any in the sample code above.  However, in my testing I sometimes called another method that simply counts rows:

```
def count_nodes(self) -> int:
    self.conn.row_factory = lambda cursor, row: row[0]
    self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
    self.query = f"SELECT COUNT(1) FROM {_NODES_TABLE}"
    result = self.cursor.execute(self.query).fetchall()
    self.cursor.close()
    return result[0]
```

The only reason for doing this was to return an int of the count, rather than a tuple inside a list.  Maybe not the best idea?

Well, if I run this code...

```
node_count = db.count_nodes()
print(node_count)
result = db.get_all_nodes()
print(repr(result[0]))
```

I get:

```
36
'A'
```

If, on the other hand, I run this:

```
result = db.get_all_nodes()
print(repr(result[0]))
```

I get this:

```
('A', 'B', 255, 1, 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G')
```

It looks like I learned something new.  The row factory, as setup in `count_nodes()` seems to belong to the connection, which must mean it affects every single cursor you create afterwards, even in a different method in the class.

What is the right way to deal with this?  Do I simply add `self.conn.row_factory = None` before returning from `count_nodes()`.  I tried, and it works...I just want to know if this is the right way to to disable a row factory.  The documentation does not seem to deal with the lifecycle of a row factory at all, this is why I thought it did not survive past the creation of the first cursor after declaration.

An explanation of this aspect of row factories would be a useful answer to this question and one that would likely help others who, like me, wrap themselves around a post for not fully understanding how they work.

Thanks @ Dan Getz

Comment: How are you using the results? What makes you think it's only getting one column?

Comment: I think I explained in the question.  I can run exactly the same SQL statement in PyCharm's DB console and get all column data.  A simple print loop as I show in the edited answer shows this as well.  I know how many columns the table has, I created and entered the data myself.  Finally, it worked just fine a couple of days ago.  I have not touched any DB code for weeks.

Comment: Could you post the output of `repr(result[0])` or similar?

Comment: Are you using a row factory?

Comment: Surely you can understand the attitude here.  Sqlite3 is one of the most well-exercised modules in Python.  It works.  The odds are 1 in 10,000 that this is not a bug in your code.

Comment: `fetchall()` returns a list of tuples. You have a type hint for your function saying it's returning a tuple. Maybe there's some strange interaction going on with that difference?

Comment: @DanGetz That's it.  Row factory.  Please see my updated question for details.  I am not sure I fully understand how this works.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, of course. I understand that it was far more likely that the error was mine. The problem is that you sometimes have no idea where the issue might be. Posting something that is reproducible is, in that context, impossible. That requires understanding --or you have to post a potentially massive amount of code and  data, which isn't fair to those trying to help.  The mention of row factories took me from not having a clue to having something to go hunt down. This was, in fact, the problem. I am sure this will be helpful to others who run into something like this in the future.